# Formatting chapter header with titlesec

Tags: titlesec

Im having troubles in formatting chapter headings. Im doing it with the package `titlesec`. My goal is to have the chapter number on the left, than a line with above the chapter name. I achieved this with the following minimal working example. But I can not figure out how to increase the size of the chapter name in this code?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.tex}
    \chapter{Chapter One}
    Text123\\
    Text123\\
    Text123
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, liststotoc, bibtotoc, 12pt, numbers=noenddot, twoside]{book} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newlength\chapnumb
\setlength\chapnumb{4cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
        \fontsize{100}{10}\selectfont\thechapter}%fontsize number
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
        \raggedleft%
        \hfill{\LARGE#1}\\
        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
        \mbox{}}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
        \raggedleft%
        \hfill{\LARGE#1}\\
        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}

\begin{document}
    \include{test1}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: You need a continuously scalable font to make `\fontsize` work as you expect. For example:
 `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: @Ivan: Many thanks for your suggestion. If I insert ```\usepackage{lmodern}``` to the code, I can change the size of the chapter number with ```\fontsize``` . But where I can change the fontsize of the chapter name?? There is no  ```\fontsize``` there

Comment: For example, change `\hfill{\LARGE#1}` in `\hfill{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont #1}`

Comment: @Ivan: THANKS a lot! That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It was already suggested by Ivan, so credits for him.

[image: x1]

[image: x2]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test1.tex}
    \chapter{Chapter One}
    Text123\\
    Text123\\
    Text123
        \chapter*{Chapter Two}
    Text123\\
    Text123\\
    Text123
    
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, liststotoc, bibtotoc, 12pt, numbers=noenddot, twoside]{book} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newlength\chapnumb
\setlength\chapnumb{4cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
        \fontsize{100}{10}\selectfont\thechapter}%fontsize number
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
        \raggedleft%
        \hfill{\fontsize{50}{10}\selectfont #1}\\  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[b]{\chapnumb}{%
        \mbox{}}%
    \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{%
        \raggedleft%
        \hfill{\fontsize{50}{10}\selectfont #1}\\ % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\chapnumb\relax}{0.4pt}}}

\begin{document}
    \include{test1}
\end{document}
```